# Print out the averages of each list, within the list, one per line in Python

Tags: python, list, function, loops, average

I define the function that I had to, where the parameter is a list with lists within it. Ex. avg([[1,2,3], [4,5], [6,7,8,9]])

```
def avg(lst):
```

I tried:

```
def avg(lst):
    return sum(lst) / float(len(lst))
```

But I don't know how to loop through the list to average out the individual lists...

Comment: what are you expecting as output?

Comment: The average of each list in lst, one per line. My first week of programming and a little lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution will require you to loop through each list contained in your top level list.

```
def avg(lsts):
    for lst in lsts:
        print(sum(lst)/len(lst))
```

Comment: This is what I had in my mind! But when I run it I get this error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

Answer (score 0):

In case you have an empty sublist:

```
In [12]: lst = [[1,2,3], [4,5], [6,7,8,9], []]

In [13]: [sum(x) / float(len(x)) if len(x) else None for x in lst]
Out[13]: [2.0, 4.5, 7.5, None]
```